# what is benefit or advantage of tomcat copyXML=true attribute on <Host> element

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I know when  copyXML attribute of  element is true, what ever context written in application META-INF/context.xml is copied to conf/Catalina/localhost/{appname}.xml.

But what is getting achived with copying. Application even works if it resides inside META-INF.

Reference:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html

In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage is that a WAR file with an embedded `META-INF/context.xml` will have that deployment descriptor copied into the place where Tomcat will check for it in preference to any found in the WAR file.

You would want to do this if you need to customize the `context.xml` for any environment-specific configuration (e.g. JNDI DataSource, MailSession, Environment, etc.).

If `copyXML` is false, you'll have to manually-extract this file and place it in the proper location beneath Tomcat's `conf/` directory.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for reply. So would not it work if context.xml lying inside META-INF only?

Comment: It will work just fine. Having Tomcat copy `META-INF/context.xml` into `conf/[service]/[host]/[appname].xml` is just a convenience for admins who want that to happen. If you don't have a need for this feature, then don't use it.

Comment: Thanks  Christopher